# Use postMessage to send variable value

Tags: javascript

I got a variable `let data = 'testing...123'` on a child site, and I embed this page on the parent site by an iframe.

How do I use the API `postMessage` to send the value of `data` to the parent site?

Assume I got a paragraph `.textHere` on the parent site and I want to use the variable from the iframe ( the child site ) on the parent site:

```
const elm = document.querySelector(.textHere);

function myFunction() {
   elm.textContent = data;
}
```

The explanation from MDN is too deep and I do not understand:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on Chile iframe

```
window.parent.postMessage(
    {
        val: 'testing...123'
    }, 
    "*"
);
```

on parent

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   console.log(event.data.val);
});
```